# javascript Looping through an array and appending the results

Tags: javascript, arrays

This command is for ffmpeg fluent

I want to loop through an array and than append the result as part of a chainable command but my attempt below doesn't seem to work. Is there another way?

```
let streamYT = (YTrtmp) => {
  let output = ''
  for (var i in YTrtmp) {
    output = output + ".output('rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/" + YTrtmp[i] + "') "
  }
  console.log(output)
  console.log("streaming to youtube")
  var proc3 = new ffmpeg({ source: inputURL, timeout: 0 })
    .addOption('-vcodec', 'libx264')
    .addOption('-acodec', 'aac')
    .addOption('-crf', 26)
    .addOption('-aspect', '640:360')
    .addOption('-f', 'flv')
    .withSize('640x360')
    .on('start', function(commandLine) {
    console.log('Query : ' + commandLine);
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
    })
    .output('./public/videos/output/' + outputName + '.mp4', function(stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('Convert complete' +stdout)
    })
    .output
    .run()
  }
```

The outputted error is as follows

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).addOption(...).addOption(...).addOption(...).addOption(...).addOption(...).withSize(...).on(...).on(...).output(...).output.run is not a function
```

Comment: You've missed a `.` before the final `run` statement.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. You need to give us a bit more than "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `.output` without parentheses. Try removing this.

Comment: To debug code like this, assign the return value of each chained function to a variable and view the value of that variable in Google's Dev Tools in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to execute the string `output`, it looks like you ought to be chaining your output commands to the end like this:

```
let streamYT = (YTrtmp) => {
   var proc3 = new ffmpeg({ source: inputURL, timeout: 0 })
    .addOption('-vcodec', 'libx264')
    .addOption('-acodec', 'aac')
    .addOption('-crf', 26)
    .addOption('-aspect', '640:360')
    .addOption('-f', 'flv')
    .withSize('640x360')
    .on('start', function(commandLine) {
       console.log('Query : ' + commandLine);
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
       console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
    })
    .output('./public/videos/output/' + outputName + '.mp4', function(stdout, stderr) {
         console.log('Convert complete' +stdout)
    });

    for (var i in YTrtmp) {
       proc3 =  proc3.output('rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/" + YTrtmp[i] + "')
    }

     console.log("streaming to youtube")
     proc3.run()
}
```